# I am unable to replace spaces with hyphens in URL in express , ejs app

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to camp name should become with hyphens with small letters in the place of spaces. Actually I want only hyphens instead of spaces.

**My route:**

```
app.get('/:campname/edit',  adminController.getUpdateCampaign);

exports.getUpdateCampaign = (req, res) => { 
const campname = req.params.Campname;

  Campaign.findOne({campname}, (err, campaign) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
              res.render('admin/campaign-edit', {camplist : campaign});
            }
          });
}
```

In `ejs` template how can I format the UURL with hyphens which match my route URL with hyphens

**ejs:**

```
 <form action="/<%=camp.Campname%>/edit" method='get'>                                                     
     <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info  dim "><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
     </form>
```

This issue is in both front end side and backhanded  and i am wondering how to solve this from few days

Comment: how do you get `<%=camp.Campname%>`?

Comment: Through for each function

Comment: I mean do you use a syntax query to obtain the value from some sort of db (e.g. mongodb, mariadb, mysql, mssql) ?

Comment: I am using mongoose  query which is mentioned above

Comment: What if you do `const campname = req.params.Campname.replace(/ /g, '-');`  in server side, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replace method.

```
<form action="/<%= camp.Campname.replace(/ /g, "-") %>/edit" method='get'>
    <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info  dim "><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: But what about server side, How can i do that. Without doing in server side it won't work .  @Md Mredul Jaman

Comment: You can do reverse replace like: Cmpaign.findOne({campname.replace(/-/g, " ")}, (err, campaign) => { }). But it will replace all "-" to space.

Comment: Campaign.findOne({campname.replace(/-/g, " ")}, (err, campaign) => {
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'